# how to configure viewflow filter?

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow, viewflow

i have viewflow install on my local computer, but i don't have the filter like a demo online: http://demo.viewflow.io
Follow the full tutorial on the quick start but
Anyone know how to activate it?

Answer (score 1):

Filter is the part of PRO packages - http://docs.viewflow.io/material_frontend.html